# Adding columns from rowwis dataframe into do command

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` with file names and my plan is to read each `data.frame` to get one huge `data.frame`, but I want to have an extra column with the file names.

What I do is going `rowwise` through the `data.frame` and use `do` to read the file and I try to attach the columns with `mutate`.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c('file1.txt','file2.txt'), 
                 b=LETTERS[1:2], 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
write.table(data.frame(c=runif(5), d=runif(5)), 
            'file1.txt', sep='\t', row.names=F)
write.table(data.frame(c=runif(5), d=runif(5)), 
            'file2.txt', sep='\t', row.names=F)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(
    read.delim(.$a, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
      mutate(A=.$a,
             B=.$b)
  )
```

For some reason, the attached columns are not `rowwise` attached as I would expect.

Is there a solution doing it like this?

### Edit

Thanks to @Matteos answer, with nesting it works like a charm! I can now clearly see from which file the  rows come from.

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(x=list(read.delim(a, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(x)
```

Comment: Give us a sample of the data frame contains the file names.

Comment: I think it would be easier to understand if your `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are different than `df`. Could you update your example and show expected output for it?

Comment: The files are different, I just wanted to create a minimal example and used the same data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `nest` and `unnest`, even if is not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve.
For example:

```
nested_out <- df %>%
              rowwise() %>%
              mutate(
                x = list(read.delim(a, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
                         mutate(A=a,
                                B=b)
                        )
              )
```

and then when you do `unnest(nested_out)` you obtain:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  a         b     a1        b1    A         B
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 file1.txt A     file1.txt A     file1.txt A
2 file1.txt A     file2.txt B     file2.txt B
3 file2.txt B     file1.txt A     file1.txt A
4 file2.txt B     file2.txt B     file2.txt B
```

Comment: This actually helps a lot! in this way I don't need to add the columns, since the column a and b are still there and I can now see where the lines are coming from.... I updated my question to incorporate your answer.